# Temporarily disable StyleCop warnings on ReSharper 6

Tags: resharper, stylecop, resharper-6.0

I downloaded StyleCop 4.6.3 which integrates with ReSharper 6 and the results are really fantastic!

However on a specific project I would like to disable the StyleCop warnings (temporarily) and enable again later on.

Is there any way of doing this? I can't seem to find it on the ReSharper menu (options, etc).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use different `Settings.Stylecop` settings for each project, just create one that ignores all the rules. Right click on a project and select `Stylecop settings` to modify them.

I think you can also disable plugins by unticking them from ReSharper->Plugins... (in version 5.1, not sure if it's the same in 6.0)

Comment: That did it! :) Thank you, I unchecked it from the Plugins and it worked. The solution with using different Settings.Stylecop settings is also interesting. Anyway, the combination of StyleCop and ReSharper rocks! :) Thanks again.