# I am using Resharper and stylecop in vs.net, can I disable stylecop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, stylecop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Temporarily disable StyleCop warnings on ReSharper 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134633/temporarily-disable-stylecop-warnings-on-resharper-6)

I have vs.net 2010, resharper and stylecop installed on my computer.

Stylecop is getting very annoying as I am working on a legacy application.

How can I disable stylecop?

Answer (score 3):

In your StyleCop install, there's a Settings.StyleCop file. You can edit this to turn off rules globally. Drag that file onto the Settings Editor executable in that file to edit it.

You can also put copies of the settings file into your projects to override the global settings.

If you're using Visual Studio integration and not just MSBuild integration, you should be able to get to the settings editor on a per-project basis by right clicking on your project and choosing "StyleCop Settings" or something like that.

And this is the source : [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643331/disabling-stylecop-rules)

Comment: At least reference your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643331/disabling-stylecop-rules

Comment: @Arran yes. sorry i didn't know how to do that. thanks. is that why you voted down?

Comment: Yes, happy to get rid of it and turn it into an upvote if you edit the post to say where you got the information from.